# What does this line mean in simple linear regression?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning. While practicing code,

```
plt.scatter(train.FUELCONSUMPTION_COMB, train.CO2EMISSIONS, color='blue')
plt.plot(train_x, regr.intercept_[0] + regr.coef_[0][0] * train_x, '-r' )
plt.xlabel("Fuel Consumption")
plt.ylabel("Emmission")
plt.show()
```

In plt.plot(train_x, regr.intercept_[0] + regr.coef_[0][0] * train_x, '-r' ), what does [0] and [0][0] mean in regr.intercept_[0] + regr.coef_[0][0] ?

Comment: what is regr? is it trained model of sklearn?

Comment: from sklearn import linear_model
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
train_x = np.asanyarray(train[['ENGINESIZE']])
train_y = np.asanyarray(train[['CO2EMISSIONS']])
regr.fit(train_x, train_y)